# why does following codes for "document.getElementById(id).onclick=[..]" shows same results

Tags: javascript

## Please explain why real code and code in comments show exact same results

```html
<p>Click button to display date</p>
<button type="button" id="button">Click</button>
<p id="paragraph"></p>

<script>
function display() {
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML=d;
}
document.getElementById("button").onclick=display;
/* Why does above line shows same results shown by:-
document.getElementById("button").onclick=function() { display(); };
*/
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In one case, when you click the button, you call `display`.

In the other, when you click the button, you call a function which does nothing other than call `display`.

The `display` function doesn't pay any attention to the arguments passed to it so the fact the event object doesn't get passed on doesn't matter.

There is no practical difference between:

```
display(event);
```

and

```
function onclick() {
    display();
}
onclick(event);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

Onclick takes a function reference. There is no difference between the two ways you posted as "display" is a function reference, and the anonymous function you entered as well is also a function reference. It just happens to invoke display inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

onclick wants a function reference. when onclick happens, js calls the function that pass to this item. when you pass "display" to it, then calls display(). when you pass "function() {...}" to it, then calls this function, and you must call display in it, not just reference "display", because js just calls the function that pass to onclick and you must call other functions yourself.